# Error: Unknown option '--no-version-vectors'- AAPT error

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, aapt

After updating the Android support library to 23.2.1-beta1, I started getting the following error. "Error: Unknown option '--no-version-vectors'- AAPT error". How can I fix it, if anybody has an idea on this error please help me to fix it? I am totally blocked with this error. I am using `Xamarin.Android`.

Comment: What versions of the Android SDK are your min and target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you have the Android SDK Build-Tools version 23.0.0 or higher installed, and additionally, make sure older versions are uninstalled (some versions of Xamarin.Android will prefer an older version even if the newer one is installed).
From: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63482/aapt-error-unknown-option-no-version-vectors

Answer (score 3):

Another cause: The latest version of the Xamarin Studio IDE seems to add (to the .csproj file) multiple  tags for what is essentially the same target.  Not sure what triggers this to happen but, once it does, the '--no-version-vectors' AAPT error will be thrown if one of the duplicated targets is from the Android SDK.  Commenting out the redundant  tags appears to address the issue.

Comment: what should I check in the csproj?

Comment: @StenPetrov, take a look at contents of the ```<Import>``` tags towards the end of the file and in the ```<ItemGroup>```.   See if any of those ```<Import>``` tags have identical (except version numbers) ```Project=``` attributes.